# Sed/awk/perl: modify text preserving parts and align to a column

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl

I have a text like this:

```
A1JOURNEY0TO1
    .BYTE 00, 00, 00
A2JOURNEY0TO2
    .BYTE 00, 01, 00
A3JOURNEY1TO0
    .BYTE 00, 01, 01
```

I need to have:

```
JOURNEY_01                               ; 00 TO 01
    .BYTE 00, 00, 00
JOURNEY_02                               ; 00 TO 02
    .BYTE 00, 01, 00
JOURNEY_03                               ; 01 TO 00
    .BYTE 00, 01, 01
```

and so on, where ";" needs to be at char 41 of the line, and values used before and after "TO" are taken from text strings at start of the line.

Comment: What do you mean with "are taken from text strings at the start of the line"? Should the addition after `JOURNEY_03` then not be `; 00 TO 03`? I can't see the pattern from such a small and irregular looking sample

Comment: I need to have "JOURNEY_xx" where xx is an incremental value from 01 to the last "JOURNEY" found, and values 'yy TO zz' taken from the 'originals" in each "A1JOURNEY0TO1".

Comment: Ok now I see it, sorry I missed before that the first word on the line changed.

Answer (score 3):

The details of this will depend on how variable your input is. If we can assume that `JOURNEY` is unchanging and that the numbers you want added to it will never be more or less than two characters (`01-99`), this will work:

```
perl -pe 's/^.(\d+)      ## ignore the first character and capture 
                         ## as many digits as possible after it.
            (.+?)        ## Capture everything until the next digit: 'JOURNEY'
            (\d+)TO(\d+) ## Capture the two groups of digits on 
                         ## either side of "TO".
            /            ## End match, begin replacement.

            "$2_" .               ## The 2nd captured group, 'JOURNEY'.
            sprintf("%.2d",$1) .  ## The number, 0-padded.
            " " x 31 .            ## 31 spaces.
            sprintf("; %.2d TO %.2d",$3,$4)  ## The start and end, 0-padded.

            /ex;   ## The 'e' lets us evaluate expressions in the substitution
                   ## operator and the 'x' is only to allow whitespace
                   ## and these explanatory comments
        ' file
```

The above can also be condensed into:

```
perl -pe 's/^.(\d+)(.+?)([\d]+)TO(\d+)/"$2_" . sprintf("%.2d",$1). " " x 31 . sprintf("; %.2d TO %.2d",$3,$4)/e;' file
```

If the lengths of the various strings are also variable, you need to take that into account:

```
perl -pe 's/^.+?(\d+)(.+?)([\d]+)TO(\d+)/
          "$2_" . sprintf("%.2d",$1) . 
          " " x (41-length(sprintf("%.2d",$1) . "$2_")) . 
          sprintf("; %.2d TO %.2d",$3,$4)/xe;' file
```

Comment: @FlavioPasqualin you're welcome. If this (or another) answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site. You can also wait and see if anything better comes up, I'm just mentioning it because you're new to the site and might not know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

With awk, and guessing what you wish

file ul.awk (edited)

```
/JOURNEY/ { jn=substr($1,2,1) ; x=substr($1,10,1) ; y=substr($1,13) ;
    printf "JOURNEY_%02d%s; %02d TO %02d\n",jn,substr("                                        ",1,31),x,y ;
    next ; }
 {print ;}
```

and then run

```
awk -f ul.awk u

JOURNEY_01                               ; 00 TO 01
    .BYTE 00, 00, 00
JOURNEY_02                               ; 00 TO 02
    .BYTE 00, 01, 00
JOURNEY_03                               ; 01 TO 00
    .BYTE 00, 01, 01
```

This is somewhat poor coding as I assumed number will always be 1 digit.

Comment: I see values "zz TO yy" always 00. But i need these values as specified in each "AxJOURNEYzTOy". X is the incremental one, but other two should be taken here...

Comment: whats the purpose of `substr("                                        ",1,31)` ?

Comment: @Jidder quick and dirty way to have 31 space, for the padding